# JSDoc Templates - "publish" not found

Tags: jsdoc

I've been able to get JSDoc3 working with the default template, however, when I try to run another template (even the one that comes with it,haruki) I get the following error:

```
js: "/path/to/jsdoc/jsdoc.js", line 308: exception from uncaught JavaScript throw: Error: Unable to load template: Module "haruki/publish" not found.
```

I've tried several other templates and get the same thing. Goven my freshman status with JSDoc I'm assuming it's some config or call issue that's tripping me up.

Comment: I generated an output using several templates so we can compare which is the most suitable according to one's needs: https://cancerberosgx.github.io/jsdoc-templates-demo/demo/ I will put more with time but I think this is really helpful to make a decision. Also its documented how each of them is generated. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set full path to template folder with publish.js file (not only template name)

for example command line parameter

```
-t templates/docstrap-master/template
```

or in config.json file

> {    ...
>       "opts": {
>           ...
>           "template": "templates/docstrap-master/template"
>       }
>   }

it works for this https://github.com/terryweiss/docstrap

for Haruki it seems to work too `./jsdoc -c conf.json -t templates/haruki` but i have another error:

> This template only supports output to the console. Use the option "-d
>   console" when you run JSDoc.

With `-d console` it prints result to console

Comment: The same thing happens when the template is configured in the `conf.json` file. Even the [examples in the docu](http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html#example) don't work like they're written. This [looks like a bug](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/506). Using "templates/default" helps in both cases. Thanks